# AS3: Model and View Communication in a Game

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, event-handling

So I'm attempting to use the MVC pattern for a game I'm working on. Everything has been going pretty smoothly so far, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get my model and my view to talk to each other effectively.

My general model structure involves lots of nested information.

```
a Level has Rooms
    a Room have Layers
        a Layer has Objects
```

Each layer has an index and a corresponding layer in the view that is rendering it. I need the objects to post an update message as they animate so it's corresponding layer in the view can update. I'm trying to use the built in event system to handle these updates.

My issue is I'm not sure how to avoid putting listeners on every object in the game - which strikes me as bad ( perhaps I'm wrong here ). If I change the rooms, the layer doesn't have a way of removing listeners from the objects in the last room because it only accesses layers through the current room. Objects are only updated when they are in the current room, so the other objects won't need to fire events.

The view is set up to cascade events to all of the children, so the root node can receive all updates ( I think I did that part correctly ), and the layer can match the target because it knows which layer it's rendering. The problem is getting the message out from the objects to the view.

Of course this makes sense to me, because I've been working with the code for a while now.

If I can provide more clarification please ask. This is my first time working with the MVC pattern, so I'm sure I could do things better.

If you have any suggestions as to how I might solve this conundrum, please share!

**Edit:** I have something working keeping track of the current layerset from outside of the view and the model which manages adding/removing the appropriate event listeners and delegating the update event to the layer as suggested. But please, anything I can do to improve this please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few solutions you could take, adding event listeners is reasonable, but as mentioned you are going to need to make sure you clean them up appropriately, but this will be a requirement with a lot of other solutions as well.

Another one would be to pass in the layer on object construction, perhaps in the form of a "parent" property. In this case the object would notify its parent whenever it has changed, then on layer update, it would go through and handle all objects who have registered as having changed. This has performance benefits in that the object could change several time between renders, but the parent would only act on this changes once, (when its been told to update itself.) In this case you would still need to make sure you clean up your references properly to avoid garbage collection problems.

Yet another solution would be objects register with them selves as having been changed, typically in the form of a simple Boolean value. In this case the parent (your layer) would loop through all children, presumable stored in some form of collection, and handle updates to all those who say they've been changed. This solution removes the dependencies from object to layer, but in extreme cases, could lead to performance issues, (Extreme case being so many objects the process of checking a single Boolean value on them is too much to handle (that'll be **A LOT** of objects))

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had a cheap solution similar to the last one that I wasn't happy with. I'll try somethings out. I guess my issue is that some of the solutions seem too complicated. It seems like there should be someway to link my model and view that's slightly more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to MVC you may want to check out the [PureMVC framework](http://puremvc.org) for AS3. When I first started learning MVC I started by trying to build my own implementation of the pattern. After trying out PureMVC I got a much better understanding of the structure of MVC.

Your rooms/layers/objects sound like they have a parent/child like relationship and may be a good candidate for the composite design pattern. Basically this is a tree like structure where you could trigger an event which would then cascade through all branches. If you do a search for 'composite pattern' you may get a better explanation of how this may work for you.

Comment: I'm familiar with the composite pattern. My view is using it. It's actually more of the reverse. I need one of the bottom nodes to be able to notify the top of the composite view stack. I will check out PureMVC though for reference. Thanks.

Comment: this was my first thought too. Solid existing implementation of MVC is a good learning tool.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Mediator pattern in PureMVC, rather than putting listeners on every object, you could have a Mediator listen to the application instance for the events. Then inside the actual objects, send a bubbling event that bubbles up the display hierarchy to the application where the Mediator hears it. Then the mediator takes the appropriate action such as sending off a notification to trigger a command with some logic, perhaps. The target of the event, would of course be the item in your world that sent the event, so if the Command would need to manipulate or inspect that item, then just pass the event.target in the notification body. QED.

-=Cliff>